# general options for graphix overriding every includegraphics settings

Tags: graphics, includegraphics, package-options, class-options, options

I have multimarkdown text compiled from an external source and which is including its own settings for each figure compiled. I would like to have a general settings at the beginning of the document which overrides these settings so that I can get a uniform figure layout.

For example, throughout the text, I would have generated blocks such as:

```
\begin{figure}[htb!]
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=400pt, height=300pt]{geometry.png}
   \caption{This is a caption.}
   \label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}
```

Where I would like to have the `width` to always be `width=0.75\textwidth`.
I originally thought (wrong) that I could achieve this by passing these options to the package before `begin{document}`:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
%...
\PassOptionsToPackage{width=0.75\textwidth}{graphicx}
%...
\begin{document}
%...
```

Comment: local settings in includegraphics will win, you would have to redefine includegraphics to change this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package [`adjustbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) contains a command `\adjustboxset*{<optoins>}` to globally append `<options>` to every following `\adjustbox{<local options>}{<contents>}` usages. With package option `Export`, `\adjustboxset*` also influence `\includegraphics`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[Export]{adjustbox}
\adjustboxset*{width=.3\linewidth}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{example-image-a}

\includegraphics[width=.6\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\end{document}
```

Output: both images have width of `.6\linewidth`.

---

The second example contains a patch to internal macro `\Gin@ii` of `\includegraphics` and a new user macro `\graphicxGlobalKeys{<options>}` which has similar functions with `\adjustboxset`:

- Without star, prefix `<options>` to every `\includegraphics`. With star, append `<options>`.
- If used multiple times, `<options>` are accumulated to the right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\graphicxGlobalKeys}{ s +m }{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \appto\Gin@opt@append{#2}%
  }{%
    \appto\Gin@opt@prefix{#2}%
  }%
}
\let\Gin@opt@prefix\@empty
\let\Gin@opt@append\@empty

\xpatchcmd\Gin@ii
  {\setkeys{Gin}{#1}}
  {%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\setkeys@three
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\Gin@opt@prefix
    \expandafter}%
    \expandafter{\Gin@opt@append}{#1}{Gin}%
  }
  {}{\fail}

% #1 = prefix, #2 = append, #3 = local, #4 = key family
\def\setkeys@three#1#2#3#4{%
  \setkeys{#4}{#1,#3,#2}%
}
\makeatother

\graphicxGlobalKeys*{width=.3\linewidth}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{example-image-a}

\includegraphics[width=.6\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\end{document}
```

Output is the same with first example.